# Is there anyway to batch rdap request for domains?

Tags: networking, dns, whois, rdap

i want to check 500 domains....does rdap support a way to do it in one api call or do I have to do each domain individually?

```
$ for in in {1..10}; do curl https://rdap.verisign.com/com/v1/domain/chovy.com -s | jq -r '.events[] | select(.eventAction | contains("expiration")) | .eventDate'; done
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

See RFC7482:

> 3.1.  Lookup Path Segment Specification
>
> A simple lookup to determine if an object exists (or not)

RDAP is JSON over HTTPS in a REST fashion. So you query for one "object", be it a domain, a host, a contact, or other things (RDAP is not only used for domain name registries but also IP ones).

There is search in RDAP (see section 3.2 in above RFC) and also various drafts about extensions (regular expressions, etc.) to be able to do a query that gets back potentially multiple results. However no registries in production enable that, and you can easily imagine that very few will, especially through public access.

Please note:

1. you do not need to do your queries sequentially in case of large batches, you can use threads or multiple processes
2. if you are not cautious (in limiting your requests) you will get at least rate limited if not completely banned for some time.

Comment: i got throttled right away with just a few manual queries.

Comment: I could proxy but its a lot slower. I need to run like 500 queries. verisign will ban me instantly.

Comment: @chovy Just wait 1 minute between each and it should be fine.

Comment: that's not possible. I need fast and instant results.

Comment: @chovy Then RDAP is not what you need to use. But since you don't explain why you need 500 "fast and instant" results, it is impossible to help you. You should get closer to your registrar of choice and see what it can provide to you through a dedicated API.

Comment: i'm building a domain suggestion tool and i need to check if domains are available. The godaddy api can do 500 at a time, but I recently discovered rdap and thought that might be better.

Comment: "i'm building a domain suggestion tool " Then clearly RDAP is not for you for this need (RDAP is to gather data about a domain - in its current form). You should look at zonefiles instead for example or really use a dedicated registrar API. For `.com` Verisign has a specific product you can leverage: https://namestudioapi.com/

Comment: What does that cost? I don't see pricing.